# Nichrome pcb soldering

Tags: soldering

I want to know if it's possible soldering pcb using nichrome wire instead of lead.
Specs say Nichrome wire melting point is around 1440 centigrade. Which is achievable with a tiny flame.

- Is there a **PCB** thermally resistant to such temperature.
- Maybe a solder paste based on nichrome alloy with a melting point below the alloy itself
- Is there another *very low* conductivity alloy which could have a melting point way below 1440C and mantain resistivity properties of the nihcrome?
- What is called the nickel alloy used for *mobo* soldering which has a elevated melting point around 485C - 565C. Can you describe some of its properties?
- What would be such devices highly unnafected by such temperatures eventually. Is there a name or catalog of this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  What are you making?  What's the ultimate purpose of the complete device (or subassembly)?

Comment: In general the study was planned as a high conductivity interface soldering betwen two pcb sheets. with a very few contact points and a very high frequency in the transmission without much thermal distortion. let's say it was a 1 gigahertz square signal for an instance which has to be preserved from one pcb to the next through a very cheap low impedance cable and a very expensive soldering paste. is this correct.

Comment: By definition, joining two metals (pcb copper and component copper) by using a filler metal that melts at less than 450C is soldering. Doing the same thing with a filler that melts at 1440C is called brazing. But the copper melts at 1085C. That's welding. Welding dissimilar metals is difficult, and avoided where possible by using mechanical connections.

Answer (score 1):

You crimp a small copper tube over it. The copper will just partialy heat due to heat transfer from wire, but if the tube is long enough and has a good crimp, then it woon't heat at all.